# I need an employment letter for immigration but I'm a freelancer

Tags: immigration, canada, employment, freelance, self-employment

I've been programming for more than 10 years, professionally for more than 5 years. I'm a computer scientist applying for immigration to Canada.

An employment letter is required. For most of my life, I've been a freelancer. My current boss is paying me as a freelancer and doesn't have a registered company. She can't give me the letter. I asked my previous boss if he could give me one, he agreed, but that means I will have to modify my CV in order to make it look like I work at my previous company, and my previous boss might soon close his company because he might apply for bankruptcy.

I will start working in another company as a freelance consultant for 3 months. After that, they either extend my contract or hire me as a senior programmer, I prefer to work as a consultant, hence it's unlikely that they will ever be able to give me an employment letter, certainly not now.

Is there a way to get the letter as a freelancer while being honest, not having to manipulate my CV?

Comment: Do you have a source that suggests that the letter must be written by an employee's employer and cannot be from a freelancer's client?  I do not see anything that suggests that.

Comment: @phoog I don't know. In my country whenever someone asks you for an employment letter, it has to be issued by a company. For instance I'm not allowed to be a member of the syndicate of computer sciences because I can't represent an employment letter issued by a company, so legally I'm not a programmer, even though I spend more time programming than most. The worst thing that can happen to your career in this country is being labeled a freelancer. I hope Canadians are more open minded but that's how it works in my country.

Comment: Related: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=286&top=6 Based on that link, you have to document 2 years of experience--you have been employed, just as a contractor.